# Why is \newcount declared \outer?

Tags: tex-core, counters, plain-tex

I'm a user primarily of Plain TeX. Lately I get annoyed about the `\outer` nature of `\newcount`, especially when I write macros which require temporary internal variables, variables which really need not be global. I'm aware that I can technically use `\count0` through `\count9` as scratch variables, but I got scared away from doing so when *The TeXbook* mentioned that those are also used as page counters, and how using them when a page shipout gets triggered can mess up page numbering.

So, my question is this: why is `\newcount` declared `\outer`? I've check that names created with `\countdef` can indeed be locally scoped within groups, and I know that changes to `\count` registers are likewise locally scoped. So why was it that Knuth chose to tag `\newcount` with the `\outer` restriction? And would there be anything preventing me from defining my own `\countdef`-based allocator, specifically one that would allow for group-local names.

Comment: Probably only DEK can answer 'why': we can at best manage 'what effects ...' :-)

Comment: Because TeX is a bad programming language and doesn't have concepts like variables or scoped functions. You have to leave your expectations from other languages' best practices at the door.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

At a technical level, making a macro `\outer` doesn't *add* anything: it's purely a restriction (much the same as `\def` is a subset of `\long\def`). Thus the reasoning here is about ensuring the input follows a particular pattern.

Register allocation is done much the same in plain, LaTeX and ConTeXt (at least fundamentally), with the exception that only plain does it with `\outer` macros. Thus there is not a 'limitation' in a technical sense in having 'normal' macros here. The one thing making them `\outer` does prevent is something like

```
\def\foo#1{%
  \newcount\mycount
   ...
}
```

which you occasionally see as a misunderstanding of the scope of TeX assignments. (I'm assuming here `\foo` is used many times in a document.)

Of course, you can still use `\outer` macros inside other macros using `\csname`:

```
\def\foo#1{%
  \csname newcount\endcsname\mycount
 ...
```

Note that the LaTeX `etex` package and 'e-plain' formats both include code to allow 'local register assignment': the `etex` package code contains *very* little LaTeX, so perhaps take a look at `\loccount` in that (*e.g.* `` less `kpsewhich etex.sty` `` on *nix).

Comment: making `\newcount` be `\outer` *did* have a positive effect in the early days of tex -- it kept one from running out of memory (`\hashcode`, if i remember correctly) when a counter was defined locally in a frequently used command.  local definition causes another instance of the command name to be defined internally, and that resource was very much smaller than it is nowadays.  without that protection, errors were much more common using latex than with plain tex for people who didn't pay attention to the need to write clean code.  (and with slower machines, ...)

Comment: @barbarabeeton That issue was what I was trying to point to with my `\foo` example. Fundamentally it's not being solved by the token being `\outer` but by it enforcing 'best practice'.

Comment: "best practice" has always been desirable, of course, but when it took maybe five minutes to compile *one* page, every "incentive" was helpful.  my guess is that knuth applied that restriction as an aid to himself.

Comment: How is it possible that your first example generates an error, but the second one doesn't? Isn't it the case that, as far as the TeX core engine (as opposed to the scanner/tokenizer) is concerned, `\newcount` and `\csname newcount\endcsname` are the same?

Comment: @EvanAad Not as far as looking for `\outer` tokens is concerned: `\newcount` is one token and is `\outer`, `\csname newcount\endcsname` is ten tokens and isn't _at the point TeX reads the definition_.

Comment: But once `\csname newcount\endcsname` is expanded, the input stream is identical to the one in the first example just after `\newcount` has been tokenized, and, since the core engine sees only tokens, it must handle both cases the same.

Comment: Oh, I think I get it. The macro's body doesn't get expanded when the macro is defined. But if you'd used `\edef` instead of `\def`, you'd have gotten an error in both cases, right?

Answer (score 12):

Counters are precious, because there are only 256 of them and several are already allocated or used by TeX: the first ten are reserved for page counters, as required by the DVI format; counters from 10 to 21 are used for bookkeeping related to register allocations and `\count255` is kept as a scratch register. The Plain format reserves other six (two implicitly via `\newinsert`).
<sub>Note: here I'm taking the point of view of Plain TeX run with the original program without e-TeX extensions.</sub>

While the number of available counters seems still large, one has to keep in mind that a `\newcount` instruction does global assignments. Let's see:

```
\outer\def\newcount{\alloc@0\count\countdef\insc@unt}
\def\alloc@#1#2#3#4#5{\global\advance\count1#1by\@ne
  \ch@ck#1#4#2% make sure there's still room
  \allocationnumber=\count1#1%
  \global#3#5=\allocationnumber
  \wlog{\string#5=\string#2\the\allocationnumber}}
```

Thus `\newcount\foo` does

```
\global\advance\count10 by 1
\ch@ck0\ins@count\count
\allocationnumber=\count10
\global\countdef\foo=\allocationnumber
\wlog{\string\foo=\string\count\the\allocationnumber}
```

Some lines above we find

```
\count10=22 % allocates \count registers 23, 24, ...
```

so we know that `\count10` stores the last allocated count register's number. The first available in user space would be number 23, but Plain TeX has three `\newcount` instructions. Thus `\newcount\foo` would print

```
\foo=\count26
```

in the log file.

Now you see that register's allocation is sequential. There's no way for “unallocating” a register without drastically changing the macros using a pool rather than a sequential strategy.

A macro definition such as

```
\def\amacro#1{\newcount\temp \temp=#1\relax ...}
```

would globally waste a register each time it's called: trust me, I've seen several instances of this error in LaTeX macros; as you know `\newcounter` and `\newcount` are not `\outer` in LaTeX. Sometimes it's `\newlength`, but the idea is the same.

By declaring `\newcount` and the other similar allocation macros as `\outer`, this kind of error is (almost) impossible to make.
<sub>Note that this would be an error also with the 32768 registers allowed by e-TeX or the 65536 made available by LuaTeX. The registers would only be exhausted later.</sub>

There are cases where `\newcount` would be legal in a macro: if we want to define an interface, say for introducing hierarchical sectional commands, we have to allow `\newcount\subsectioncount` as part of the (fictional) command

```
\definelevel{subsection}{...}
```

But here it's not “user space”: the definition of `\definelevel` is made by a programmer, who knows (or, at least, should know) what's being done. A programmer would type

```
\csname newcount\expandafter\endcsname\csname#1 count\endcsname
```

in the code for `\definelevel`, overriding the outerness of `\newcount`.

Comment: 'Counters are precious': well, since 1990 there have been 64k available! (OK, e-TeX allocates the first 256 in such a way as they are more efficient than the 'extended pool', and you have to take those for `\insert`s from the 'basic' set.)

Comment: @JosephWright I was taking Knuth's point of view.

Comment: Yes, I can see that: just wanted to note that the restriction is altered in newer engines.